# What does MD545FD/A model of iPad means?

Tags: ipad

Usually there is a model number with `AXXXX`. What does MD545FD/A mean? At [Identify your iPad model](https://support.apple.com/pl-pl/HT201471) you can see there are avery of them with `AXXX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on the box my MacBook Pro came in the **Model No:** is designated as e.g., **A1398** and the **Part Number:** is in the form of ***AlphaNumeric/A*** as is with the part number you've shown.  So with an iPad I'd assume it's the same, a part number, as there would be no reason to have different inventory control systems.  If you Google "MD545FD/A", it shows as an Apple iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular 64GB.